# python3 mysql import parsing values error

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I'm getting this error when running my python code which I wanted to have insert data from a csv file into mysql...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mongo2sql.py", line 16, in <module>
    mycursor.execute(drop, ctbl)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 248, in execute
    prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 632, in prepare_for_mysql
    raise ValueError("Could not process parameters")
ValueError: Could not process parameters
```

Here's my py code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="host",
  user="user",
  passwd="user",
  database="db"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

drop = "Drop Table User;"
ctbl = "Create Table db.User (`_id` VARCHAR(255) not null primary key,`accountStatus` VARCHAR(255) null,`active` BOOL null,`allowedPartners` VARCHAR(255) null,`allowedProviders` VARCHAR(255) null,`capabilities` VARCHAR(255) null,`createdDateTime` DATETIME null,`firstName` VARCHAR(255) null,`lastName` VARCHAR(255) null,`mail` VARCHAR(255) null,`role` VARCHAR(255) null,`sourcePartnerId` VARCHAR(255) null)"
mycursor.execute(drop, ctbl)
mydb.commit()
print("Table Dropped & New created \n Working on inserting data...")



sql = "INSERT INTO vdmUser (_id,accountStatus,active,allowedPartners,allowedProviders,capabilities,createdDateTime,firstName,lastName,mail,role,sourcePartnerId) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,)"

with open("userlist.csv", "r") as a_file:
    for line in a_file:
        stripped_line = line.strip()
        print(stripped_line)
        mycursor.execute(sql,stripped_line)
        mydb.commit()
        print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

I'm kinda new to python so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your csv into individual components and pass the resulting iterable to `.execute()`.

```
import csv

with open("userlist.csv", newline='') as a_file:
    reader = csv.reader(a_file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)  
        # you may want to validate your csv content's before, 
        # but anyway...
        mycursor.execute(sql, row)

     # better to commit only once at the end of the import
     # 1/ it's much faster and 2/ it's atomic, so if anything
     # goes wrong you can just fix the csv and relaunch the 
     # whole import (else you'd get a partial import)
     mydb.commit()
     print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

This being said, mysql/mariadb [already provides support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) for [tabular data import](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html)